# Holonomic and Topological Quantum Computing

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer

In topological quantum computation, anyons are braided in spacetime, performing non-trivial evolutions of some degenerate groundstate.

In holonomic quantum computation, the system is braided in parameter space, performing non-trivial evolutions of some degenerate groundstate (via the holonomy of a non-abelian connection).

What are the key differences between the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In brief, the [holonomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomy) depends on the area enclosed by the path in parameter space, and is therefore sensitive to perturbations of the path, e.g. its length. In contrast, a topological evolution is largely independent of the path geometry, and depends only on topological data, specifically [homotopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy) (e.g. how many times a path encircles a singular point, which for a pair of anyons is $r=0$, with $r$ the relative coordinate). In particular, two homotopically equivalent paths lead to the same evolution. This makes topological quantum computing much more robust in principle.

Comment: holonomic quantum computing with a flat connection would be just as robust, I would hope

Comment: @David If the curvature vanishes but the evolution is non-trivial, I'm pretty sure that's called topological quantum computing :)

Comment: Haha well I guess the anyon stuff should just reduce to holonomy of flat connections then. Interesting.

Comment: @David Yes, that's exactly right. Actually all particle exchange statistics can be understood in terms of holonomy of a flat connection. See the beautiful article by [Leinaas and Myrheim](http://www.ifi.unicamp.br/~cabrera/teaching/referencia.pdf).